# Magento 2: How to create CSV with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: magento2, csv, product-import

In my Magento store, I am facing one issue that I am not able to import the product with special characters. For the CSV base I have followed the below tutorial. Can anyone please help me how can I encode with UTF-8 in CSV when writing it?

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-a-csv-file-to-download-using-magento-2/

Note: It's custom product import

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your string to UTF-8 by using default PHP function.

```
mb_convert_encoding(string, encode_type)
```

Please check below example for more details.

```
$products[] = array(1,'Test 1','test 1',100);
$products[] = array(2,'Test 2','test 2',299);

foreach ($products as $item) {
     $itemData = [];
     $itemData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item[0], "UTF-8");
     $itemData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item[1], "UTF-8");
     $itemData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item[2], "UTF-8");
     $itemData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item[3], "UTF-8");
     $stream->writeCsv($itemData);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello @Siv, is it working for you ?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below code snippets,

```
        //Declare column and data
        $result[] = [
        'Column1',
        'Column2'
        ];
        
        $result[] = [
        'data01',
        'data02'
        ];
        
    
        $varDir = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR)->getAbsolutePath();
        $directory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $tmpFolder = 'customfolder';
        $directory->create($tmpFolder);

        $filename = "filename" . ".csv";
        
        if ($this->_file->isExists($varDir . $tmpFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename)) {
            $this->_file->deleteFile($varDir . $tmpFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
        }

        $filePath = $varDir . $tmpFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

        $this->csvWriter
            ->saveData(
                $filePath,
                $result
            );
```

and add dependency to your constructor,

```
        use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
        use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File;
        use Magento\Framework\File\Csv;
```